# How to make Brakeman ignore certain paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, brakeman

I'm trying to configure Brakeman for my Rails projects and I want it to ignore certain directories and files. I can't find an option to specify paths to exclude. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the flag (also known as 'option') `--skip-files` to ignore specific files; however, there is no support for skipping entire directories.

Furthermore, there is the inverse flag `--only-files` which **does accept** directories, and there is the *option* to use `--skip-libs` to only skip the `lib` directory.

I recommend that you check the output of `brakeman --help` for more options.

If you really want to skip an entire directory, you could do something like the following command line.

```
ls app/some/dir/ | paste -s -d , - | xargs brakeman --skip-files
```

If you are using Brakeman as a library, then you can pass the files by running `:skip_files` as follows.

```rb
Brakeman.run(:app_path => "my_app", :skip_files => Dir["my_app/bad/path/*"])
```

Answer (score 5):

There is now support for skipping entire directories. See https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/brakeman/4.3.1

`brakeman --skip-files file1,/path1/,path2/`

Answer (score 0):

After digging more into the source code, I found that Brakeman::Scanner generates an AppTree object, which takes an argument called skip_files.

Source is here: https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman/blob/master/lib/brakeman/app_tree.rb#L12

If you look further down in that file, you can also see what directories Brakeman looks at when it scans. It turns out some of my exceptions are already excluded by Brakeman's cleverness!